# How to read rosbag file which is in .db3 / .mcap format using python without ros installed?

Tags: ros2

I am unable to find how can i read rosbag file without ros installed

Tried with some libraries but it is supporting only .bag file, need some library to read the messages
I am unable to find how can i read rosbag file without ros installed

Tried with some libraries but it is supporting only .bag file, need some library to read the messages

Answer (score 0):

The [python package rosbags](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/) can both read and write ROS1 and ROS2 .bags (both sqllite and mcap), and is easy to use and well documented:

```
pip install rosbags
```